# JSON: How do i make array to several arrays?

Tags: jquery, json, each

I return an JSON array from PHP file with 200 ID's. (ID : number).
I would like to just have 18 of theese ID's so that i send only 18 ID's to a new PHP file, then after 2 seconds, i would like to send the next 18 ID's of the JSON to the new PHP file as well, until there are no more ID's in the JSON array to send.

```
    $.get('get.php?randomize=1', function(data) {

        var json = data;

        $("#wallpaper").load('get_random.php?json_18=' + encodeURI(data), hideLoader());    

    });
```

As you see, i have stored the JSON in a variable called json. But i dont know how to split it up for each 18 ID's. I have read about .each function in jQuery, but i don't understand it well. I was hoping someone could help me.

Comment: Instead of splitting like that, why not use the standard offset / numResuts methodology?

Comment: Never even heard of that. What is it? Is there any good place to start reading about it?

Comment: You would change your callable to something like, `get.php?randomize=1&offset=0&numResults=18`.  Your offset would increment each time, returning the next 18, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/2bZHP/4/:

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var spliceAt= 5;
var trigger = setTimeout(function() {
  var toSend;
  if(data.length>spliceAt)
  {
        var left= data.slice(0,spliceAt);
        var right = data.slice(spliceAt);
        data = right;
        toSend = left;
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 2000);
  }
  else
  {
      toSend = data;
  }
  //$("#wallpaper").load('get_random.php?json_18=' + encodeURI(toSend), hideLoader());
  alert(toSend);
}, 2000);​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get('get.php?randomize=1', function(data) {

   var json = data;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
      setTimeout("$('#wallpaper').load('get_random.php?json_18=' + encodeURI(json.slice(i*18,(i*18)+18)), hideLoader());", i*20);
   }    

});
```

& check it out, maybe some error with syntax of setTimeout, didn't check it.

Answer (score 1):

From [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
$.each([52, 97], function(index, value) { 
  alert(index + ': ' + value); 
});
```

will show:

```
0: 52
1: 97
```

So, the function iterates over each element, and applies a function to each one, passing the item index in the array and the item itself.

You can use slice() function in this way:

```
var taken = 0, step = 18;
var subset18;
while (taken < json.length) {
    subset18 = json.slice(taken, taken + step);
    taken += step;
    // do something with subset18
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp